# More frequent Windows 10 UWP background GPS tracking

Tags: c#, timer, uwp, background-task

I am creating a UWP to track GPS location, for now my idea is to leverage `IBackgroundTask` since I cannot rely on the user to have screen on all the time.

And I think I need to use `TimeTrigger` to wake up under certain intervals then get current GPS location data. But according to the document of `TimeTrigger` the minimal interval I can set is 15 minutes, which causes 2 problem for me:

- 15 minutes probably is OK for somebody who walks, but pretty bad for cycling. I need more frequent internal.
- For real world testing by using my phone, I have to walk outside for 30 minutes to get 2 data? This sounds a bit ridiculous and very inefficient.

Any idea, what is a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experiences about making the location history UWP app in 2016, then I can share my thought about it. I hope this helps you.

1) Background Task

Essentially, I belive that this way is not good for location tracking. The reason is .. 1) Yes, 15min interval is tooo long for location tracking and 2) OS can revoke and suppress the runnning of background task with or without notice for the app. Manage this situation from the App is too hard.

2) Extended Execution

With this feature, you can prevent that your app entering suspend when the app is background or minimized. App keep running - this means that you can use the ordinal dispatch timer solution to get the location with your preferred intervals like as 1min, 45sec, etc. And, Extended Execution have an option to use "ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking" enum.

But this feature also have one consideration point. OS can revoke - terminate your session anytime - battery shortage, CPU time shortage, the app drain the resource, etc.
When the session is revoked, we can nothing to do - we can't re-launch the session because the revoke situation is not solved - revoked again immediately. This means the loss of location data.
In my case, this - loss of location data - is not acceptable for my App scenario. I've  realized that extended execution is not suitable for my app.

But, if it's acceptable -like as fitness app or something like hobby app - , Extended Execution is good option.

Notes

- If you have AC power, the revoke will be rare. Extended Execution is good option.
- You can use the restricted capability to prevent the revoke of extended execution. But, if use this capability, you cannot use the store to deploy your app.

3) GetGeopositionHistoryAsync

I believe that this is best for UWP app scheme - does not rely on BackgroundTask nor Extended Execution. OS itself keep the location history - we can just retrieve it with this API. We don't have to get the location data periodically by ourselves.

But there is one barrier - to use this API, you need to get the authorization from Microsoft. Because this feature is a type of restricted capabilities.
I have not tried to get the authorize, thus I can't tell you this is difficult or not.

[App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)

Comment: pnp0a03 shameless request... do you maybe have some time to help out another win dev MVP? ;) In our hobby app, we tried to add this extended execution and indeed are getting some user errors reporting it sometimes fails. Maybe you can tell us a bit what we can adjust to better this? Code is here : https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/src/Kliva/ViewModels/RecordViewModel.cs#L176

Comment: @Depechie Excuse me but I can't help your project - I want to spend my time to my project. In fact, I could not overcome the difficulty of Extended Execution and strange behavior of Win10M imprementation on my 2016 project and I stopped the project. After that, I've noticed that the existence of location history api but it was too late.

Comment: Well not played with Geo history feature myself. But for a cycling tracking app that would not be ideal I guess :/

Comment: Thanks, your 2nd point is especially important. I have ever used several app to track my hikings cross all over the world, but all of them lost lots of location data. I guess they used the same solution. It is especially worse in foreign countries while I did not have cell service. I guess in this case I probably will combine background task and extended execution together for long distance hiking. It looks like it is almost not possible to have a decent GPS tracking app without Microsoft's special approval.